# Simulation of Poisson cluster process on linear network

Tags: r, spatstat

On pp. 73-74 in ["“Stationary” point processes are uncommon on linear networks"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sta4.135)* by Adrian Baddeley, Gopolan Nair, Suman Rakshit, and Greg McSwiggan, the authors introduce a Poisson cluster process on a linear network and subsequently demonstrate a simulation.

Unfortunately, I cannot find related code. Does `{spatstat}` provide an algorithm to simulate such a process?

On pp. 24-25 in ["Analysing point patterns on networks — A review"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2211675320300294)* by the aforementioned authors and Tilman M. Davies one can read:

> "Point process models which exhibit clustering (positive association between points), such as Poisson cluster processes and Cox processes [...], can easily be constructed on a linear network, [...]".

__

*You need sth. like an academic vpn to access and download the pdfs without any expense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to ask the authors directly.

Here is some code (written by Greg McSwiggan) to generate a Thomas cluster process on a network.

```
rThomaslpp <- function(L, kappa, mu, sigma) {
 X <- rpoislpp(kappa, L)
 Y <- density(X, sigma)
 Y <- eval.linim(Y * mu)
 Z <- rpoislpp(Y, L)
 return(Z)
}
```

The network is `L`. The parent intensity is `kappa` (points per unit length), the mean number of offspring per parent is `mu` (dimensionless), and the cluster size is `sigma` (length units).

Example:

```
require(spatstat)
X <- rThomaslpp(simplenet, 4, 6, 0.07)
plot(X)
```

This code will be added to the next version of the package `spatstat.linnet`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Excuse me, I will do so in the future. I thought asking on an open access platform has advantages for others.

Comment: Dr. Baddely you are so optimistic. Some authors do not even bother to reply. Once someone told me to post on github if I want a reply. So I did. Since then I have always posted on StackOverflow.